# Customize select into a simple icon

Tags: html, css

I have a simple select statement:

```
<select class="select ui-icon ui-icon-chevron-down" style="width: 10px;height: 19px;" type="position_last">
        <option value="" style="display: none"></option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
      </select>
```

I don't want it to show as a normal select, I want to show it as a simple icon.
I'm not that good with CSS, so I don't know if that can be done or not.

Comment: add `class="form-control"` if you are using bootstrap 3.3.1

Comment: I'am not realy using it for a form 
what I am tring to do is make it look like an icon then when we press it we can see the options.
so using the "form-control" is not that much important

Comment: Why do you want to make a select box look like an icon. It's a huge user experience flaw. Select box is meant to look like select box, which gives user idea that they can click on it to get more options to select. Just an icon may ruin it.

Comment: I am using a widget wich has on top many icons as buttons but this time I need a select 
I am using it like that just to go with the general theme of my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how.
I just have to make its backround transparent

```
<select class="select_ticket form-control ui-icon icon-list" style="background-color: transparent; border: medium none;">
        <option value="" style="display: none"></option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using additional library

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

you just need to include the library and add this code to your javascript

```
$(".select").selectpicker();
```

Comment: I'am not trying to make a select look like a bootsrap style 
I'am trying to make it an icon